# Can clang-modernize update Windows/MFC codebases?

Tags: c++, mfc, clang

In an attempt to add the "override" keyword to my codebase, and without any better options, I've tried to get clang-modernize to update my source files. Eventually clang chokes on the various safety macros in the Windows headers.

```
clang-modernize -risk=safe -summary -add-override -include-from=Src\inc Src\AuditFile.cpp -- -std=c++11 -ISrc "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include" "-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include" -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_DEBUG -D_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -D_AFXDLL -D_DLL -fms-compatibility -fmsc-version=1000 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -w -D_M_AMD64=1 -D_M_X64=1
```

First "compilation" error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h:366:9: error: unknown type name '__possibly_notnullterminated'
typedef __possibly_notnullterminated WCHAR *PNZWCH;
        ^
```

I'd like to know if anyone has worked through these issues, and how.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question a bit late, but I've seen this issue.
Make sure that you include all the include directories. And the system includes should not be used with -I, but with -isystem.

Hope that helps.